# How to properly trasmit dynamic web content in j2ee web-app?

Tags: javascript, html, jakarta-ee, client-server, dynamic-html

I have java web-app and dynamically transmit the data to the server. What I do is wrap a json data in the javascript variable like this.

```
var foo = {}; //json content that fills up the entire page
```

and use javascript to spread out the content.

But, how good is this practice? Because I have seen lots of websites, may be because of SEO, which finds hard to crawl over AJAX contents or because servers are fast nowadays, they dynamically create content, not in my way using javascript, but with embedded content in html tags. I wonder how this is possible.

I figured that one way to do is to do it under php. Php and html goes side to side while coding in php. That way, you don't have to expose javascript variable, rather you can do it in server, and pass it to client.

I wonder if any other languages can do the same.

Comment: I think you question is too broad.

Comment: This might be too broad, but I don't exactly get the approaches to get to. If only I could grab a path to explore the possibilities, then to select.

Comment: List your requirements, it will be easier for people to point directions